# DOMPDF does not render text on Unix

Tags: php, dompdf

I have a problem with a DOMPDF script that worked fine on Windows and IIS but now fails on MacOSX running Apache 2.2.

The PHP version is 5.3 and DOMPDF is 0.6.0 beta3. As far as I can understand I have followed the setup steps correctly.

The only font in use is Helvetica which should be supported out of the box by DOMPDF. Correct?

I have set chmod 1777 to the font directory. I have NOT run the load_font.php script but when using helvetica I should not have to, correct?

Paths to the lib and font directories are set correctly.

The PDF file is created, the table borders are showing and a image is inserted on the right place. The only thing not showing is the text. If I render the HTML to a browser everything looks fine.

I guess there is something about fonts when creating PDFs on unix that I don´t understand. Does anyone know what I could be missing? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you copy from one computer to another? Check dompdf/lib/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache (or the .dist file). If you have, at any time, used load_font.php the paths may have been modified and may no longer be correct.

Comment: Yes I did copy it from the working configuration on a Win/IIS. I can only find a dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php file, not the one without the .dist in the filename. However if I echo the constant DOMPDF_FONT_DIR I get the correct path: /Volumes/Data/website.com/classes/dompdf/lib/fonts/. And in the .dist file paths are using the constant like this: 'normal' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'Helvetica'. Also there is a Helvetica.afm.php file present in the fonts directory. Do I need to run the load_font.php for use of helvetica?

Comment: Problem solved. It was UTF-decoding that caused the error. A little bit frustrating but once discovered a very obvious error. Pay notice to encoding when generating PDFs... it matters =)